# CTE get rootname

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I got a very simple table, but I'm struggling with CTE:

```
ID | Parent | Name
---+--------+---------
 1 | NULL   | Root
 2 |   1    | Child1
 3 |   2    | Child2
```

I'd like to receive a result like this:

```
Element | Root
--------+------
Root    | Root
Child1  | Root
Child2  | Root
```

My CTE is something like this...

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT a.id, a.parent, a.name, 1 as lvl
    FROM table1 a

    UNION ALL

    -- Perform the recursive join
    SELECT a.id, a.parent, a.name, Lvl+1 AS Lvl
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN cte pa ON cte.parent = a.id
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
```

Now I would aggregate (max) and (self)join but it seems kinda bad/wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little complicated, because you are traversing ids but in the end, you just want names.  The following handles this by looking up the names *after* the recursive CTE has found the root ids:

```
with cte as (
      select id, parent, name, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select cte.id, t.parent, cte.name, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on t.id = cte.parent
      where t.parent is not null
     )
select top (1) with ties cte.name, coalesce(tparent.name, cte.name) as root
from cte left join
     t tparent
     on tparent.id = cte.parent
order by row_number() over (partition by cte.id order by cte.lev desc)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f5227866251d49a5fad10f9ed8b5b7c0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: there must be a little twist, as the result is like -> Root|Root Child1 | Child1, etc

Comment: @jaster . . . I seem to have copied the wrong version over.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful... How would I encoporate joins here? Lets say I don't get the name, but something from a different table

Comment: @Jaster . . . Then you would have a different question.  New questions should be asked as questions rather than as comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  with cte as (
      select id, parent, name, name as root
      from t
      where parent is null     
      union all
      select t.id, t.parent, t.name, cte.root
      from cte 
      join t on t.parent = cte.id
  )
  select name, root
  from cte
```